# XNA Displaying splash screen while content is loading

Tags: windows, xna, splash-screen

I'm trying to include splash screen into my XNA project while content is loading. I tried few tutorials but none has helped me. I was trying load content in update method, forcing draw method etc. Since I'm doing my project on Windows PC only I'm looking for a solution to display splash screen (propably animated) in the center of desktop. When content is loaded splash screen should disappear and the game screen should pop up.

I'm looking for some advices and tips how do it since I can't find any help on the Internet.

Personally I was thinking about using Forms but I don't know it well to use it properly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are loading content, you are probably making a method call that spans over many frames. If you make that call on the GUI thread, you will freeze the game, which isn't what you want.

Instead, call the method inside a `Task`, and set your game's state as 'loading', and when the task is done, set a state that indicates the task is done.

Then, in your drawing method, you can do something like this:

```
if (state == State.Loading)
    // draw loading screen
else if (State == .....
```

Comment: I just didn't think about it in that way. I wanted to make some nice splash screen on the desktop but sometimes easier solutions are better. Thank you very much for the reply it seems to fit my expectations.

If someone has other solutions to share I would appreciate their help.

Answer (score 1):

Extending on what Kendall Fray said, You could use game states like so:

```
    public static GameState currentGameState = GameState.Loading;

    public enum GameState
    {
        Loading, Whatever
    }
```

and on Update or draw:

switch (currentGameState)
            {
                case (GameState.Loading):
           //draw load screen
                    break;
                case (GameState.Whatever):
                    break;
            }

Comment: Sure, I wanted to use game state enumeration even before I asked a question but thanks to Kendall I realised that my problem can be solved by using this simple game state pattern. Anyway thanks for reply!